# How to change “/login” url with Fortify?

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

In laravel 9 with Fortify Authentication I see in routes

```
  GET|HEAD        login ................................................................................................................................................... login › Laravel\Fortify › AuthenticatedSessionController@create
  POST            login .............................................................................................................................. generated::kNTXAE1j2bp8Zq09 › Laravel\Fortify › AuthenticatedSessionController@store
```

and my login page is opened by “/login” url.

How can I to make this login as “/admin/login” url?

Leaving all Fortify functionality as it was before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `FortifyServiceProvider` in the `boot()` method, you should add

```
Fortify::ignoreRoutes();
```

before the default configuration.

It will tell Fortify to ignore the build-in routes.

Then you should copy Fortify's routes (`./vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php`)
to your own routes (`./routes/web.php`) file.

Then in your `web.php` file you can make changes accordingly.

Comment: For me, to make this one work had to set the ```Fortify::ignoreRoutes();``` line inside the ```FortifyServiceProvider```'s ```register()``` method and not the boot method. Like @Pingo's version of the solution says.

Answer (score 2):

For my case:

Laravel Framework 9.25.1 and "laravel/jetstream": "^2.11" which contains "laravel/fortify": "^1.13.3"

1. Prefix `/admin` may add in `config/fortify.php` file. In this file find `prefix` key and add you prefix. Example:

```
return [
    // code...
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    // code...
];
```

2. I add to `app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php`
   for `register` method:

```
public function register()
{
    Fortify::ignoreRoutes(); // add this string
    // ... next code
}
```

for `boot` method:

```
public function boot()
{
    Route::group([
       'namespace' => 'Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers',
       'domain' => config('fortify.domain', null),
       'prefix' => config('fortify.prefix'),
    ], function () {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(base_path('routes/fortify.php'));
    }); // this closure

    // ... next code
}
```

3. Copy `vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php` to `routes/fortify.php` and change routes in this file. The same path is specified in my closure in `app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider@boot`.

Comment: If you are not modifying the `vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php` file, then this is the way to go. For me, I had a conflict with the `logout` route name. So I just need to add a prefix like this `'name' => 'api.'` and kept the vender file `base_path('vendor/laravel/fortify/routes/routes.php');`

Answer (score 1):

There is also a more personalized option where you can rename any route separately.

Add the following lines in `config/fortify.php`:

```
 return [
      'paths' => [
        'login' => '/admin/login'
       ],   
  ];
```

You can do this with all named routes,

Sorry for the rusty English :)